# PHP - Can if-statement being ignored/skipped for some reason?

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

What I want to achieve : if a user pass a PHP parameter to the server, it will return the **same parameter value** back to the user, instead of returning the **value from the database itself**.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $classId = $row['classId'];
    
    if($obj['classId'] != ""){
        $classId = $obj['classId'];
    }

...
}
```

For some reason, I found out that the $classId still using the $row['classId'] value, even if the user had inserted the classId parameter. It seems that the PHP has ignored/skipped the if statement.

```
 if($obj['classId'] != ""){..} //SKIPPED?
```

The code works fine right now and I do get the return of the same parameter value. Only one user out of hundreds got this issue and I assumed that the he/she had sent the parameter when the server was busy.

Questions:

1.Can if-statement being ignored/skipped for some reason?
2.How to make the if-statement more reliable even if the server in a high-traffic?

Excuse me for posting here. I don't find the right keywords for googling myself.

Thank you.

Comment: so what are asking about is why `$obj['classId'] != ""` alway `false` or what ?

Comment: The $obj['classId'] are just like $_POST['classId'] .  The if-statement supposedly skipped only if the user had not assigned any value to the param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try having your if statement more strict.

```
    if($obj['classId'] != ""){
        $classId = $obj['classId'];
    } else {
        $classId = $row['classId'];
    }
```

I'd also recommend using isset instead of checking for an empty string.

```
if(isset($obj['classId'])) { }
```

Comment: I also like `empty()` over `isset()` sometimes, but likely a preference matter, since the two functions differ in what they do.